# Callback: "Object is not a function"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to use CoffeeScript to setup an AJAX callback function like so:

### The Pattern

```
function doAjax(callback)
{
  $.ajax(url, data)
    .done(function(){
       // ... do stuff here ...
       callback(true);
    }).fail(function(){
       callback(false);
    });
}

function doSomething()
{
  doAjax(function(result){
    if (result == true )
       console.log('success');
    else
       console.log('failed');
  });
}
```

I am using the following CoffeeScript to do this (this is within an object):

### CoffeeScript

```
doAjax: (callback) ->
  $.getJSON(url)
    .done( (data) ->
      if something == true
        callback(true)
      else
        callback(false)
    ).fail( () ->
      callback(false)
    )

doSomething: () ->
  this.doAjax(function:(result)->
    if result == true
      console.log "true"
    else
      console.log "false"
```

It results in the following compiled JavaScript like this:

### Compiled JS

```
MyObject.prototype.doAjax = function(callback) {

  return $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
    if (something == true) {
      callback(true);  // <--- The error happens here
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  }).fail(function() {
    callback(false);
  });
};

MyObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {

  return this.doAjax({
    "function": function(result) {
      var message;

      if (result === true) {

        return console.log("true");
      } else {
        return console.log("false");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And I get the error (at the marked line above):

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong in my CoffeeScript here?

Comment: You are not passing a function to `doAjax`, but an object. The error seems pretty clear.

Comment: Are you talking about `this.doAjax(function:(result)->`? Is that not how you define an anonymous function?

Comment: You defined anonymous functions in `doAjax`, you do it the same `() ->`

Comment: Ah! I don't know how I missed that. Thank you. If you want to put your comment as an actual answer I will accept and upvote.

Comment: There are answers already, I upvoted myself. Note that you can remove all those parentheses in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
this.doAjax(function:(result)->
```

to this

```
this.doAjax((result)->
```

functions in coffeescript are declared with `() ->`. `function:() ->` creates an object with a property called `function` that contains the actual function

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are trying to callback function to perform some operation after successful ajax call, but you are calling the object as function.Define some function and use it to callback.thank you, for further assistance please report to me.